What is the meaning of "%CPU" when using GNU `time` command
I doubt my understanding of the output from running the GNU time command is correct. I am now wondering what the CPU percentage actually indicates.
On macOS I have installed the GNU time utility gtime using homebrew and run a very simple command to check its function:
/usr/local/bin/gtime -f '\ntime: system %S user %U elapsed %e CPU %P \nstat: %x'  echo hi

hi

time: system 0.00 user 0.00 elapsed 0.00 CPU 100% 
stat: 0

running a simpler command using the same utility with less flags:
/usr/local/bin/gtime echo hi
hi
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 75%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 676maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (1major+420minor)pagefaults 0swaps


The man pages states

%S   system (kernel) time in seconds  %P   percent of CPU this job
got  %U   user time in seconds 

Does this mean the command was inefficient, using 100% of the CPU, or does it mean it's very efficient, or neither.
I have run some other far more complex shell scripts using gtime and they show a range of CPU 5% – CPU 9% which lead me to ask this question.

On macOS the %CPU indicates what percentage time the software in question was using on the CPU, during the time period covered by the measurement. It is measured relative to a single core of the CPU, so 100% means 100% of one core. You can see percentages over 100% since all modern CPUs have multiple cores.

Smaller numbers mean less CPU time was used, which is good from a resource-management standpoint, but that measurement alone is not sufficient to tell you if your software is efficient or not, because you don't have anything to compare it to.
For example, if you had one sort algorithm that sorted a set of data in 10 seconds using 100% of a CPU core during that time, that's just one data point. Was that algorithm efficient or not? Who knows?! But if you get a second data point by switching to a different algorithm and it sorts the same initial data set in 5 seconds using 100% of a CPU core during that time, you now know the first algorithm wasn't as efficient as it could be.
Knowing that a single-threaded application is using 100% of a CPU core may be a sign that the work it's performing is CPU-bound. That is, it's not waiting for things to get read from or written to RAM, storage, the network, or some other I/O device; the only thing holding it back from performing faster is how much work it needs to do on the CPU, and the fact that it's not parallelizing its work onto other CPU cores.
If you have single-threaded software that never uses 100% of the CPU, then the work it's doing is not being limited by the power of a CPU core. It's possibly being limited by other factors such as available RAM, or waiting on I/O. Or maybe it's just supposed to be a quiet background process that monitors things, not something designed to process a bunch of data as quickly as possible.

@John The echo command used 100% of one core during the nothingth-of-a-second that it took to run. Perhaps it only took, say, a paltry 10 CPU cycles to run, and it was able to use 10 CPU cycles in a row to do its job; it didn't take long enough to run to require the kernel's scheduler to pre-empt the process to give other processes time on that CPU core. So during the time it ran, which was a vanishingly small amount of time, it wasn't forced to yield the CPU core it was running on.

@John I don't mind as long as the formula is correct and helpful. :-) I already said "…during the time period covered by the measurement" in my first sentence, which I thought covered what you asked in your temporary followup comment.
